# Exception on release COM pointer

Tags: c++, com

I am getting `read access violation exception` in `Base` class destructor as `root_dse` is going out of scope after `CoUninitialize();`

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <ActiveDS.h>
#include <memory>

#pragma comment(lib, "activeds.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "adsiid.lib")

using namespace std;

class Base {
protected:
    CComPtr<IADs> root_dse = nullptr;
public:
    Base()
    {
        CoInitialize(nullptr);
    }
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    void do_stuff() override {
        const auto h_result = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://rootDSE",
            NULL,
            NULL,
            ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
            IID_IADs,
            (void**)&root_dse);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> base = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    base->do_stuff();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I ensure that `root_dse` is `release` before `CoUninitialize();` to avoid `read access violation exception`?
Note: All derived classes are using `root_dse` so it should be in the `Base` class.

Comment: `root_dse.Release();` before `CoUninitialize`. It's generally not a good idea to put init/uninit in class constructor and destructor respectively. After all initialization is a thread specific action.

Comment: Alternatively, create another layer in your type hierarchy, and do the CoUninitialize in the 'baser' base class.

Comment: @RomanR. I think I didn't get your last line `After all initialization is a thread specific action` this is a single threaded application.

Comment: @GemTaylor so that `baser` only contains `CoUninitialize` in its destructor?

Comment: You initialize COM for a specific thread. Then keep in mind that initialization might fail because COM is already initialized for another apartment mode. If it's a single threaded application just have COM initialization stuff right in main and not in constructor. It's not that it can't work your way but you are shooting your leg and confusing things for no good reason.

Comment: @RomanR. got it, thanks! ;)